# TypeError: fun() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given error in sciply.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

I am attempting to use scipy.optimize.curve_fit but appear to be coming across some issues. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/Sams PC/Desktop/')
data1=np.loadtxt('Titrations6.txt')
data2=np.loadtxt('Concentrations3.txt')
protein=data2[:,0]
ligand=data2[:,1]
b=data1.transpose()
for x in b:
    def fun(kd):
        return np.array((B+kd-(np.sqrt(((B+kd)**2)-4*A*C)))/2*A)

    from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
    intensity=[x]
    xdata=[protein,ligand]
    ydata=intensity
    A=xdata[0]
    B=xdata[0]+xdata[1]
    C=xdata[1]
    print (xdata)
    print (ydata)
    popt, pcov=curve_fit(fun,xdata,ydata, p0=(1))
```

Data1 is a 8x6 matrix, and data2 is a 2x6 matrix. I want my function to loop through and fit each column of data1. When I run this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: fun() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Which I don't quite understand. I've only given fun one argument, but it's saying that it's been infact given 2 arguments. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: 
I've added the data I'm using below for some clarity. This is what I Get when I do print (data1) and data2.

```
[[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.        ]
 [0.41437697 0.23486582 0.3946243  0.37853352 0.35563582 0.39256528
  0.32845158 0.37614817]
 [0.56069666 0.47530052 0.59725788 0.65505611 0.53696339 0.56234781
  0.59790931 0.61088421]
 [0.80054062 0.6781974  0.79853213 0.88599716 0.80807803 0.84945185
  0.82345173 0.8316841 ]
 [1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
  1.         1.        ]]
[[0.59642147 0.06      ]
 [0.5859375  0.11928429]
 [0.56603774 0.29296875]
 [0.53003534 0.62264151]
 [0.41899441 1.21908127]
 [0.38861986 3.05865922]]
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't define function in a loop. Also the model function, f(x, …). It must take the independent variable as the first argument and the parameters to fit as separate remaining arguments.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean. Are you talking about in the curve_fit line? Because that's how I have it set up there (xdata is my independent variable and ydata is what I want it to fit).

Comment: I'm talking about the ```def fun(kd): return ...```. You give one argument to fun, which is assumed to be the independent variable by default in curve_fit. I'm guessing A, B and C is what you want to be optimized. Then you should definitely add them as function arguments too.

Comment: I tried that (I used both xdata, and A, B, and C). The latter gives this error TypeError: fun() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'B' and 'C' and the former gives this error minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats..

Comment: I think you need to look with more care at the `curve_fit` docs.  Play with its examples.  Then try to construct your own, but without the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is you didn't specify any parameters to optimize. See [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). Also I'd recommend importing and defining functions outside your loop. 
The basic form of a model function is:

```py
def fun(independent_variable, *parameters_to_optimize):
    # return a combination of the independent variable and parameters
```

An example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Generate some noisy data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = x**2 + 3*x + np.random.normal(0, 0.5, len(x))

# define the model I want to fit
def fun(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b * x + c * x ** 2

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fun, x, y)

# plot
plt.plot(x, y, label='data')
plt.plot(x, fun(x, *popt), label='fitted')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
print(popt)
# [-0.07309343  3.01359277  0.99988617]
```

[image: Plot]

In your example there are two mistakes:

```py
def fun(kd):
    return np.array((B+kd-(np.sqrt(((B+kd)**2)-4*A*C)))/2*A)
```

- For curve_fit there is nothing to optimize in this function, it has only one variable which is assumed to be the independent one.
- curve_fit expect a numeric output from the model function, not an array

Without seeing the actual data, that's what I can say.

Comment: Xdata is my independent variables, and in this case, A, B, and C are simply defining which values of xdata to use (I find this cleaner and easier than using xdata[0] and xdata[1] in my actual function). I only want to optimize (or rather solve for) kd. I want my function to provide me an array of values (values used for each row of xdata), and then attempt to match those values to my ydata. From that, I want a single output value for kd.

Comment: I'd suggest reading [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), because that's definitely not how you do it.

Comment: I have, but I find that somewhat confusing to follow (e.g. why they define their dependent variable y on the output of their function using specific a b and c values). My setup is similar to them (my independent variables are also an array, i.e. for each function it should only be using  the first column of xdata), and it should be matching the first column of my ydata. If you are familiar with matlab, they have a very similar setup (which I assume sciplot is mimicing) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402316/using-least-squares-in-python-like-lsqccurvefit-from-matlab

Comment: One quick thing to add, kd is what I want optimized. The other variables I have provided the values in xdata. I do want one output (e.g. whatever the value for Kd is that makes the function matche my ydata).

Comment: @samman I understand this, but try to mimic what I did in the example. You have a model function, you have parameters to optimize. It's the same really, you just need to translate it. Without the actual data I cannot effectively test your code, just recommend solutions.

Comment: I see. So your A,B and C are the values you are solving for, and your x is your independent data (so in my case, kd would be the A,B,C and my x would be my xdata). The only thing I still am a bit confused to is I have technically 2 independent data sets that are being somewhat modified to be used in my function (so my A, B, and C in my data sets). They are my "x" so to speak. However, curve_fit only uses one "x" array, not multiple. So I don't quite know how to implement multiple independents data sets in my function using curve_fit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204582/discussion-between-samman-and-peter-leeh).